# Can I ping any user I want to take a look at my question?

Tags: support, notifications

Assume there's a user with the name Bob on Stack Overlow who might be able to solve my question. If he hasn't seen my question yet, can I ping him to come and take a look?

So when I post

> @bob please have a look at it.

will Bob get my notification in his inbox?

Comment: Are downvotes on support questions really necessary? Even though the question originally had the [meta-tag:discussion] tag, it was obvious that this is a support question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, he won't be notified; nor would I support any [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to enable that prompting mechanism, as it would inevitably lead to an avalanche of spam notifications and requests for our more 'famous,' or recognisable, users.

The only users that will be notified of an @comment are those who have participated in the comment thread if the question or answer, to which it's attached, or a user that's edited/improved the question/answer and the person whose question/answer it is.